# Connect from Windows 8 from home network to office Linux server

Tags: networking, windows, putty

My client's office has a Linux server. Whilst I am in the client's office, I am able to connect to their Linux server from my Windows 8 laptop using PuTTY with their wifi connection.

I wonder is it possible when I am working from home, would I be able to connect to the client Linux server using my wifi connection?

My client does not have a VPN facility to provide me.  I have to travel a long distance to work with my client.

Answer (score 1):

The SSH port of that server needs to be reachable from your home Internet connection for that to work. This either requires

a) a VPN

or

b) a port forwarding in router of the client office that exposes the server's SSH port to the Internet (I am assuming here that the client office uses some kind of NAT router).

If your client doesn't have a static IP address for their Internet connection, you also need a way do determine their current IP address for this to work, e.g. some kind of DynDNS service.